# Application Insights Access Token

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to figure out how to get an application insights access token but the link I've found seems to be broken:

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID

Is there a better link to look at? I need the access token in order to send up a query for ADO to generate some charts on my dashboard to use for better querying of data.

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still create query API keys. However, they are **deprecated and should not be used anymore** for new scenarios.

Instead, you should move to [AAD-based authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview).

From the Azure Portal on your AppInsights resource:

[image]

[image]

[image]